# Affidavit from father for student to travel to Egypt for internship

Tags: visas, study, pakistani-citizens, egypt

I checked with the Egyptian embassy for documents required for a visa. I am a citizen of Pakistan and am traveling for an internship with AIESEC. I'm currently a student and my dad will be financing me so they asked for the affidavit. What needs to be written in the affidavit?

Comment: What is your nationality and what is the purpose of your trip to Egypt?

Comment: Pakistani. I'm going for an internship with AIESEC.

Comment: Go to your nearest oath commisioner or district magistrate office, outside there are many advocate offices who know how to make an affidavit.

Comment: To the closevoters: The OP specified that he is traveling for an *internship*, not long-term employment. Internships are typically of short duration, not too dissimilar from "working holidays".

Answer (score 1):

In short, whatever you told them your father would be doing for you, you need to get him to swear an affidavit saying that. So if you told them your father would be funding your entire trip, he needs so say that he will do that. Make sure the affidavit includes basic information, such as how long the trip is and how much money is likely to be involved so that the embassy is sure he understands what he is promising.